# Does the spin travel as a wave?

Tags: waves, quantum-spin

The electromagnetic field (wave) has a spin. The electromagnetic wave travels at the speed of light. Does the spin associated with the electromagnetic wave travel at the speed of light too? If so please provide the necessary equations.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of the classical EM wave as made up of a herd of photons, then you could talk about the spin of the photons.

At the level of particles, you usually do not think of actual movement for spin, but something different. Spin is a mathematical property.

If you think of an electron spinning around an axis, some things are not understandable intuitively, like half spin.

You could think of a spinning particle as rotating like a polarized light.

For photons, to visualize spin, use Riemann Silberstein decomposition of Maxwell's equations. You can think of E and B fields rotating as for polarized light. The E and B fields are components of the photon's quantum state.

1. mechanical spin: angular momentum in classical mechanics, and if you think of electrons spinning like that, you get to the magnetic dipole
2. magnetic spin: non-relativistic QM describes it as the particle interacts with an external magnetic field.
3. classical Lorentz transformation: if you apply Noether's theorem to Lorentz transformations, you get a 2 tensor, and if you only use the spatial components, you will get two constituents, angular momentum, and spin, which is based on the internal properties of the particle.

Now in your case, it is true that EM waves travel in vacuum at speed c, when measured locally. You could then say that the angular momentum of this wave travels with it at speed c.

If you talk about photons, they travel in vacuum with speed c when measured locally. You can talk about the spin of the photons as internal property of the photons, traveling with them at speed c.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in principle you could make a beam where spin density is modulated: You would have to control the amplitudes of separate beams, possibly with polarizer crystals, then mix them up according to your desired modulation wavefunction.